# Antivirus whitelisting pains

Tags: windows-installer, obfuscation, antivirus

I'm a small software vendor (a 1-person company). People download my [software](https://www.querystorm.com) and pay for licenses.

The issue I'm having is antiviruses keep flagging my installers, resulting in 50% of my potential customers getting nasty looking warnings when they try to install the software.

I use a Commodo code signing certificate to sign my installers and dlls, but the antiviruses also require the exe to have a certain reputation (popularity) in order to not complain. It's a classic catch 22 situation.

As it turns out, I can ask the antivirus companies to whitelist my installers, but it seems I have to go through this procedure with all vendors every time I create a new version. This happens every few days/weeks.

Is there an easier way?

Note: I do use obfuscation in a few of my dlls. Could this be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

We haven't found a solution to this either. We release [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) every 1 or 2 months and we pass through the same "hell".

The only solution is to increase the time between releases and make yourself a timeframe between the moment you build your release package and publish it on your website (2-3 days). In that timeframe you can submit it to most antivirus vendors that detect you and have the problem solved.

To see which vendors will report on you, use https://www.virustotal.com/
So you don't waste time whitelisting your software with all vendors (*that is just crazy*).

*Update*: more details about our [AV struggles](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/antivirus-whitelisting.html).

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect larger companies (way larger than mine at least) to also be having this problem. Reducing the release frequency is likely what I'll do, but yeah, it's a pretty nasty handicap right off the bat. Virustotal actually doesn't seem to help. It doesn't find any vendors flagging me, but when I try Norton on a VM, it pops up a scary warning saying the installer is "Unknown" and recommends removing. This makes things even more difficult since virustotal says Norton didn't find a threat (it didn't, but it still popped up the "uknown" warning). Ugh.